# how to save username and email to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have watched some tutorial about save user info to DataBase after register or SignUp in the app but the problem that he save all the users by there uid and what i want is to save the users by there usernames what do you think is the professional or the better way to do that or it doesn't matter to chat app

```
@IBAction func SignUp(_ sender: Any) {
        if  username.text != nil, email.text != nil, password.text != nil, fullname.text != nil {

            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    AlertController.showAlert(self, titel: "Error", message:".Fill all fields\n .User do exists\n .Network error ")
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    return
                }
                let uid = user?.uid
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://,,,,,,,,,.com").child("profile_image").child(uid!)
                if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1){
                    storageRef.putData( imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                        if error != nil{
                            return
                        }
                        let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                        let ref = Database.database().reference()
                        let usersReferance = ref.child("users")
                        let newUserReferance = usersReferance.child(uid!)
                        newUserReferance.setValue(["fullname": self.fullname.text, "username": self.username.text, "email": self.email.text, "password": self.password.text, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
                    })
                }
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            })
}
}
}
```

[image: this is how it shows in firebase]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to save the users by their username yes you can do as follow

```
@IBAction func SignUp(_ sender: Any) {
        if  username.text != "", email.text != "", password.text != "", fullname.text != "" {

            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    AlertController.showAlert(self, titel: "Error", message:".Fill all fields\n .User do exists\n .Network error ")
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    return
                }
                let uid = user?.uid // here you are providing userID
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://.........com").child("profile_image").child(uid!)
                if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1){
                    storageRef.putData( imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                        if error != nil{
                            return
                        }
                        let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                        let ref = Database.database().reference()
                        let usersReferance = ref.child("users")
//                        let newUserReferance = usersReferance.child(uid!) //here in ref you are creating a node with UID

                        //use your username
                        let newUserReferance = usersReferance.child(username.text!)

                        //set child values here as you doing 
                        newUserReferance.setValue(["fullname": self.fullname.text, "username": self.username.text, "email": self.email.text, "password": self.password.text, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
                    })
                }
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            })
        }
    }
```

For 2 . 1) I do not think it will be a bette approach as if you set node with username if while signUp other user filled same username data will be replaced with new data

2) if you use some checks that username is valid or not it will work , but just for concern need a additional reference in database for it to check username is available or not

-- Do as check in whole database that username is taken or not

-- or make a node with list of usernames and and get all those in array and check offline for a fast response with textfield validations or can even put observe event

Comment: username text property will never be `nil`. Its default value is an empty string. You should test if it is not empty `username.text?.isEmpty == false` or if it is not equal to double quote  `!= ""`

Comment: oh yes thanks I didn't noticed it , I just answered his points

Comment: your answer contain personal info please delete it

Comment: will i ever be needed the user uid and how to set that value in firebase i have tried   newUserReferance.setValue([ "uid": uid])

Comment: if you are using username no need to make use of UID but yes make sure you get UID when a user login as for logout from DB you need UID and to update data in DB Nodes you need username , if you want save user UID also in DB for reference ..Edit is approved.. Thanks

Comment: @mazenqp While this is an answer, it's *really bad* to store user data in this fashion. You should *always* store users using uid as the key and store user names as a child node. There are dozens of reasons why but the most important is that user names change and if that happens in your app, you will have to find every node in your entire Firebase with that username, delete it, and re-write it. Whereas if the uid is used as a key, the user name can be changed with essentially no effort. Also, certain characters cannot be used in a key so you will have to parse every user name, every time.

Comment: @iOSGeek The statement *if you are using username no need to make use of UID* is not really accurate as if you use authentication, uid's make that work, which then ties back to Firebase Rules leveraging auth.uid for security. Also *and to update data in DB Nodes you need username* would only be correct if rules are set to validate against that username. If read and write are set to true or set to auth = true then data can be written to any node by any authenticated user regardless of user name. That goes back to my above comment where implementing uid's as keys is best practice in Firebase.

Comment: I mentioned that this is actually not a better approach to use username instead of UID as UID is always going to be unique and will be used for authentication but here he asked to make use of username so I just wrote how he can use , yes not a better approach as I mentioned

Comment: ok if it is not better approach i will use UID and thanks for help

Comment: @jay thanks for explanation for the second part of my question you really helped me